Facing npm not found issue with sonarscanner latest
Recently we have updated sonarscanner image
During sonar app stage, facing this npm not found issue
npm: command not found
My sonar-app stage is like
sonar-app:
  <<: *tpl_build_gcp
  stage: sonar_audit
  image:
    name: sonar-scanner-cli:latest-release
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache chromium
    - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
    - cd app
    - ls
    - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    - npm run unit-test
    - ls
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN} -Dsonar.projectKey=application/path -Dsonar.sources=src     


I'm not sure from which version you updated the docker but it looks like npm was removed from this docker in 2022: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli-docker/commit/b20faa10e751d2248cfbc551d79e8340ea49683b This was the corresponding ticket: https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/DOCKER-69

In your script you need to add :
- apk add --no-cache chromium
- apk add --update nodejs npm

